# Increment an index variable based on an existing sequence in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I will like to know if it's possible to create an **new index** in pandas based on the **evolution of a column values** (like history of a variable). Normally I would do this in a looped coding way (for loops or similar) but I'm putting my effort to learn more about Pandas.

In this example the column **'Tags'** contains **'tag1', 'tag2' and 'tag3'** but they may be mixed when changing from the 1st to the 2nd and from the 2nd to the 3rd (see the example list below).

The **new index** should begin from 0 at the first row and increment only when 'tag1' appears (but increment only once, not each time that 'tag1 appears). Then it will remain the same while **'Tags'** is **'tag2'** and **'tag3'**. Finally the **new index** will increment again and only once when the **'tag1'** appears again.

If you agree with me, I can run a row-wise operation within a for loop, using a 'idx++', but I want to write a pandas code. I though in [pandas.DataFrame.applymap()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), but I'm not sure if this is the way.

If you find a correct way of doing this, I'll appreciate your solution. Thanks in advance!

```
# example input
phase_col=['tag1','tag1','tag1','tag1','tag2','tag2','tag1','tag2','tag1','tag2','tag3','tag3','tag2','tag3','tag2','tag3','tag3','tag3','tag1','tag1','tag2','tag2','tag3','tag1','tag2','tag3','tag1']

df= pd.DataFrame(data=phase_col, columns=['Tags'])

# I need this column:
df['new index']='' # increment once for each sequence of tag1->tag3

# example of an ideal output:
print(df)

    Tags new index
0   tag1    0     
1   tag1    0     
2   tag1    0     
3   tag1    0     
4   tag2    0     
5   tag2    0     
6   tag1    0     
7   tag2    0     
8   tag1    0     
9   tag2    0     
10  tag3    0     
11  tag3    0     
12  tag2    0     
13  tag3    0     
14  tag2    0     
15  tag3    0     
16  tag3    0 
17  tag3    0     
18  tag1    1     
19  tag1    1     
20  tag2    1     
21  tag2    1     
22  tag3    1     
23  tag1    2     
24  tag2    2     
25  tag3    2     
26  tag1    3
```

Comment: Based on the logic provided in your write up, I would expect the fifth "tag1" (index 6) top have a "new index" of 1, why does it not?

Comment: Hi @pshep123 , what I need is that the **new index** remains the same for the whole sequence (_tag1_ up to _tag3_) and then increment once for the next sequence.

I edited the paragraph where the logic is explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you right, the new series starts when 'Tags' is 'tag1' and the previous 'Tags' is 'tag3'.  If so, this should do it:

```
df['new index'] = 0
df['new index'][(df['Tags'] == 'tag1') & (df['Tags'].shift(1) == 'tag3')] = 1
df['new index'] = df['new index'].cumsum()
```

Comment: Thank you, nice solution! I'll take this as a valid answer because the desynchronization only happens between other tags and not between _tag3_ and _tag1_

Comment: @fedeman, hope it works for you. Would appreciate an up vote if it is useful.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I can not vote cause I don't have a min of 15 reputation (I'm new here), but I'll give you as soon as I reach the 15 points...

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't realize that.  We both learned something here.  Thank you!